# 32-bit Linux Assembly - Linking files together (gas and ld)

Tags: assembly, linker, ld, gnu-assembler

I wrote a function called strlen:

```
.section .text
.global strlen
.type strlen, @function
strlen:
... code ...
```

I assembled this like so:

```
as --32 strlen.asm -o strlen.o
```

Then I wrote a program in asm to print argv which I want to link with this. I assembled that the same way. Now I want to link them together so that the actual program can use strlen. I tried:

```
ld printnum.o strlen.o -m elf_i386 -o printnum
```

but that yields:

```
printnum.o: In function `loop':
(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `strlen'
```

I must be missing something really simple. Thanks!

Comment: Please include _all_ code, you never know what might be relevant. The fact that you're asking this question means you're the least likely person to be able to decide this accurately :-)

Comment: I know it's a visibility problem, not a code problem. Both asm files assemble with no errors and visibility would have to do with the .global portion of the code or something of that nature. I even recall reading that you need .global on the function to make it visible which is why we define _start as a global.

Comment: To further that: http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/as/Global.html#Global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier I stupidly ran `strip` on strlen.o which obviously removed all of the symbols. Good job me.